# Will an ultrawide monitor work with my Ubuntu laptop?

Tags: xorg, debian, external-monitor

I'm thinking of buying one of [these new ultrawide monitors](http://www.lg.com/us/ultrawide-monitors) and I was wondering if anyone has had any luck using them with Ubuntu or any other Debian variance. I'm planning to plug it into a Lenovo X230 laptop and I was also wondering if it has enough graphics juice to drive this monitor (I'm not really planning to do much gaming).

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

What I can tell is that the 29" models like [29EA93](http://www.lg.com/de/monitore/lg-29EA93) do work out of the box using Dsplay Port. With HDMI you might have to modify the xrandr configuration as explained in [this article at Debian forums](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=78330).